# C# dynamically add setting to settings file

Tags: c#

I'm currently using the below code to add a setting to my settings file, but keep getting the following error:

> The type 'providercollection' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly" at this line:
>   Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];

How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance.

```
  System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("CustomSetting");
  property.DefaultValue = "Default";
  property.IsReadOnly = false;
  property.PropertyType = typeof(string);
  property.Provider = Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];
  property.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), new System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());
  Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
```

Comment: You must add a reference to assembly

Comment: If you don't know how to add a reference to an assembly, may I suggest you go and run through some basic C# tutorials?

Comment: it works i'm stupid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

1. Go to solution explorer
2. Right click on references
3. Add reference
4. search for System.Configuration
5. Add System.Configuration